# wxt terminal for gnuplot on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gnuplot, macports

I've installed `gnuplot` on my Mac OS X 10.8 using `MacPort`, but as far as I understand, only `AquaTerm` terminal is available for me now (`wxt` is "unknown or ambiguous terminal type"). However, I need `wxt` terminal badly. Is it possible to install some patch with `MacPort`(or without it), so that to enable this terminal?

Comment: You can get a list of available terminals via `set term`

Comment: the `wxt` terminal requires `libwxgtk2` ... I'm not sure if a simple `sudo port install libwxgtk2` and then rebuilding gnuplot will work or not.

Comment: This blog says the fink version automatically has it: http://blog.debsankha.net/2011/03/getting-gnuplot-wxt-terminal-in-mac-os.html That said, this question better belongs to super

Comment: @Yuji Many thanks, it worked! You should post it as an answer, so that I can choose it as the right one.

Comment: Thanks, but the question really belongs to supeuser or apple.stackexchange.com ... I'm just happy I could help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall your current version of Gnuplot and then install the `+wxt` **variant** of gnuplot.

`port variants gnuplot` to list available variants.

`sudo port install gnuplot +wxwidgets` to install this variant, but be careful it may conflict with `wxwidgets_devel`.