# Add WXT terminal to GNUplot 4.6.1

Tags: gnuplot

This SO thread offers solutions for installing GNUplot with WXT terminal on OSX:

[Install WXT terminal on GNUplot in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001847/wxt-terminal-for-gnuplot-on-mac-os-x)

but when I follow the suggestions the install fails with this:

> house@The-iMac:~$ sudo port install gnuplot +wxwidgets
>   --->  Computing dependencies for freetype
>   --->  Configuring freetype
>   Error: org.macports.configure for port freetype returned: error copying "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_freetype/freetype/work/freetype-2.4.10" to "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_freetype/freetype/work/freetype-2.4.10-x86_64/freetype-2.4.10": file already exists
>   Please see the log file for port freetype for details:
>       /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_freetype/freetype/main.log
>   Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
>   Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade fontconfig failed

I can't really remove Freetype as too many other programs depend on it.

I followed the remove/re-install advice:

> Uninstall your current version of Gnuplot and then install the +wxt variant of gnuplot.
>
> ***port variants gnuplot*** to list available variants.
>
> ***sudo port install gnuplot +wxwidgets*** to install this variant, but be careful it may conflict with wxwidgets_devel

but it fails with the same error.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it got that I found so many broken file links that I exported the Macports installs list, removed all Macport installs and the entire program, and re-installed Macports.

Installed GNUplot with the WXT terminal and it now reports WXT as one of the available terminals.